# Google cards suddenly showing mixed languages

Tags: localization, google-discover

My Google cards are acting weird. 40% of the cards are in other languages which I have no clue of. It's sometimes Urdu, sometimes Russian, and sometimes god knows which one.

[image]

I have tried hitting "not interested" on several of these, but it keeps coming up in my feed. I'm pretty much sure that I have not changed any language and settings on my phone. I haven't had any recent app installs too.

Anybody help me with this?